# Java - How is processing time split between threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to threading in Java. I've been reading some online tutorials, but haven't found much material that addresses how the processing time is split between threads.

I created a Runnable class:

```
public class HelloThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

        int i = 0; 
        while(true) 
        { 
            System.out.println("New Thread" + i);
            i++; 
        }
    }
}
```

and I start the new thread in:

```
public static void main (String[] args) { 

    // Start a new thread
    Thread helloThread = new Thread(new HelloThread());
    helloThread.start(); 

    int i = 0; 
    while(true) 
    { 
        System.out.println("hello from main thread" + i);   
        i++; 
    } 
}
```

The output alternates between the message in the helloThread and in the main thread. How is the processing time split between these two threads? I played around with the setPriority() method, but even when I set the helloThread to a priority of 10, the main thread still gets some processing time.

Thanks!

Comment: your processor is too fast. You should use Thread.sleep(int milli sec.) and cover the sleep method in try-catch block.

Comment: Assuming that you have a multi core CPU there is no need for scheduling as every thread has its own core. So thread priority does not play a major role here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot predict when a thread will run (as you assume). Even if your thread priority is 10, it is no guarantee that you threads will run at all. Threading depends on the concrete JVM (there are different JVM implementation) as well as on the underlying operating system and even on your hardware (like how many cores you have).

In your example, you have two threads (the main thread and your `HelloThread`). Both are running. So it is a completely OK that both threads run and print messages. It is the purpose of threads to be scheduled alternating and run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

It is because they have the same priority. You can add statement like

`System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getPriority() );`

Both threads should have priority of 5 based on your example

As Thomas Uhrig explained, even with higher priority, the other thread will still get scheduled and executed. It is nondeterministic.